# Looking for a way to automatically send to Splunk Jenkins pipeline duration per stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, splunk

Is there a way to send Jenkins pipeline duration per stage information to **Splunk** for all pipelines automatically.

I have installed the **Splunk** forwarder plug-in in Jenkins. But that only seems to forward duration per job.

(I can alter every pipeline to send the data, but that seems like an unnecessary amount of work)